# Как получить значения полей метода объекта javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

Есть на сайте [плагин календаря](https://pinpoint.world/documentation-booking/), подключение и подтягивание данных с бд которого происходит следующим образом:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#DOPBSPCalendar1").DOPBSPCalendar({
    "calendar": {
      "data": {
        "bookingStop": 0,
        "dateType": 2,
        "language": "en",
        "maxYear": 2020,
        "reinitialize": false,
        "view": false
      },
    },
    "days": {
      "data": {
        "available": [true, true, true, true, true, true, true],
        "first": 7,
        "firstDisplayed": "2019-09-01",
        "morningCheckOut": false,
        "multipleSelect": true
      },
      "text": {
        "names": ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
        "shortNames": ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"]
      }
    }

  });
});
```

Меня со всего перечня интересует ключ поля `"firstDisplayed": "2019-09-01"` - как его получить в переменную? (конечно же без изменения скрипта плагина)

Прохожу циклом по объекту **DOPBSPCalendar**

```
(function($) {
    $(window).on('load', function () {
        var cal = jQuery("#DOPBSPCalendar1").DOPBSPCalendar("days");
            for (key in cal) {
               if (key == "DOPBSPCalendar") {
                  console.log(key + " -> " + cal[key]);
               }
            }
    });
})( jQuery );
```

Но, по итогу получаю лишь функцию с дефолтными значениями..

```
DOPBSPCalendar - > function(options) {
  /*
   * Private variables.
   */
  var Data = {
    "calendar": {
      "data": {
        "bookingStop": 0,
        "dateType": 1,
        "language": "en",
        "languages": [],
        "pluginURL": "",
        "maxYear": new Date().getFullYear(),
        "reinitialize": false,
        "view": false
      },
      "text": {
        "addMonth": "Add month view",
        "available": "available",
        "availableMultiple": "available",
        "booked": "booked",
        "nextMonth": "Next month",
        "previousMonth": "Previous month",
        "removeMonth": "Remove month view",
        "unavailable": "unavailable"
      }
    },
    "days": {
      "data": {
        "available": [true, true, true, true, true, true, true],
        "first": 1,
        "firstDisplayed": "",
        "morningCheckOut": false,
        "multipleSelect": true
      },
      "text": {
        "names": ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
        "shortNames": ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: вы бы хоть ссылку на документацию по данному плагину привели

Comment: @teran пожалуйста - https://pinpoint.world/documentation-booking/
Я просто подумал, что это вопрос скрипта и не просто не догоняю как ухватить поле

Comment: А добавляете этот код прямо на страницу, или в виде ссылки src=... ? (можно придумать костыльное регулярное выражение)

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME если правильно понимаю вопрос, то на страницу. Там получается так, что скрипт плагина берет значения зашифрованные в `json` `array_push($html, '        jQuery("#DOPBSPCalendar'.$id.'").DOPBSPCalendar('.$this->getJSON($atts).');');`

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME вы предлагаетесь пройтись по `html` коду, который отдает страница - верно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Костыль с регуляркой:

• match возвращает массив совпадений. Всё, что написано в скобках - получается отдельным элементом массива, поэтому после всей строчки, можно получить нужные скобки по счету `[2]`...

• `\s` англ. space - пробел, `*` — ноль штук или несколько.

• `[^,]*` - что угодно, кроме запятой, ноль или много раз.

```js
var moo = document.getElementById('moo');

var first = moo.innerHTML.match(/firstDisplayed("|'|`):\s*([^,]*)/)[2]; // Просто совпадение 

var exact = moo.innerHTML.match(/DOPBSPCalendar1(.*)firstDisplayed("|'|`):\s*([^,]*)/s)[3]; 
// Совпадение с конкретно указанным, если их несколько
// Флажок /s = single line

console.log( first || 'Не найдено' );
console.log( exact );
```

```html
<scrip-t id="moo">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#DOPBSPCalendar1").DOPBSPCalendar({
    "calendar": {
      "data": {
        "bookingStop": 0,
        "dateType": 2,
        "language": "en",
        "maxYear": 2020,
        "reinitialize": false,
        "view": false
      },
    },
    "days": {
      "data": {
        "available": [true, true, true, true, true, true, true],
        "first": 7,
        "firstDisplayed": "2019-09-01","morningCheckOut": false,
        "multipleSelect": true
      },
      "text": {
        "names": ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
        "shortNames": ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"]
      }
    }

  });
});
</scrip-t>
```

Проверка регулярки → https://regex101.com/r/OgvImv/1/

P.s. хотя не знаю, что для вас значит "не трогать код". Можно было так:

```js
var obj = {
  "calendar": {
    "data": {
      "bookingStop": 0,
      "dateType": 2,
      "language": "en",
      "maxYear": 2020,
      "reinitialize": false,
      "view": false
    },
  },
  "days": {
    "data": {
      "available": [true, true, true, true, true, true, true],
      "first": 7,
      "firstDisplayed": "2019-09-01", 
      "morningCheckOut": false,
      "multipleSelect": true
    },
    "text": {
      "names": ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
      "shortNames": ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"]
    }
  }
}

var first = obj.days.data.firstDisplayed;

console.log( first );

/*

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#DOPBSPCalendar1").DOPBSPCalendar( obj );
});

*/
```

Comment: спасибо, но нужно что-то докрутить. в первом варианте получаю начало верное, но затем лишний хвост
`"2019-09-01","morningCheckOut":false,"multipleSelect":true},"text":{"names":["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"],"shortNames":["Su","Mo","Tu","We","Th","Fr","Sa"]}},"deposit":{"data":{"deposit":0,"type":"percent"}`

во втором - ошибку
`SyntaxError: invalid regular expression flag s`

"P.s. хотя не знаю, что для вас значит "не трогать код". Можно было так:"
А что вы предлагали подставить вместо obj, чтобы заработало?

Comment: Регулярку докрутил... она не учитывала, что там может не быть пробела. А по obj... Там ведь `.DOPBSPCalendar( ... )` — функция, которая получает объект в виде аргумента и что-то там делает с его значениями. Соответственно, объект можно записать не прямо в скобках, а отдельно сохранить в переменной `var obj = { ... }` тогда можно будет эту переменную использовать и как аргумент для .DOPBSPCalendar() , и чтобы оттуда достать нужные свойства.

Comment: да, вот это выражение заработало  - спасибо!
а по obj почему я вас спрашивал, т.к. вот такое присвоение и выражение дает ошибку
`var obj = jQuery("#DOPBSPCalendar1"); var first = obj.days.data.firstDisplayed;`